# JHipster Registry How to config git username and password

Tags: jhipster-registry

I am trying to set up the JHipster Registry with a local git config server.
`--spring.cloud.config.server.composite.0.type=git 
--spring.cloud.config.server.composite.0.uri=http://mygit/abc.git`
those 2 config works but my git need permission to login.
now I got the error: Authentication is required but no CredentialsProvider has been registered

Does anyone know where can I set up the username and password?

I tried:
`--spring.cloud.config.server.git.uri=
--spring.cloud.config.server.git.password=
--spring.cloud.config.server.git.username=`
not working

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
--spring.cloud.config.server.composite.0.username=
--spring.cloud.config.server.composite.0.password=
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the following in the bootstrap-*.yml

```
 cloud:
    config:
      server:
        bootstrap: true
        composite:
          - type: git
            uri: https://github.com/awnali/configuration
            username: ${spring.cloud.config.server.git.username}
            password: ${spring.cloud.config.server.git.password}
            default-label: main
```

and then run the application with the following command:

```
java -jar target/jhipster-registry-6.8.0.jar --spring.profiles.active=prod --spring.cloud.config.server.git.username=***** --spring.cloud.config.server.git.password=*****
```